# Tab close button position

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qtabbar

I want to style my tabs in my Qt app as follows:

[image]

I used following style sheet:

```
QTabBar{background-color: #fff; border-top: 0px;}
QTabBar::tab {
    border-image: url(:/New_UI/tab_inactive.png) 7 17 7 2;
    margin-left: 2px;
    border-right: 17px;
    border-top: 5px;
    border-bottom: 5px;
    font: 400 9.2pt "Segoe UI";
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 0px 13px 0px 5px;
    max-height: 26px;
 }

QTabBar::tab:selected, QTabBar::tab:hover {
    border-image: url(:/New_UI/tab_active.png) 6 17 6 2;
}

QTabBar::close-button {
    image: url(:/New_UI/tab_close.png);
    subcontrol-origin: padding;
    subcontrol-position: right; 
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;

}
```

The result is as follows (close button position is not as I wanted):

[image]

What am I doing wrong & how could I get my desired result ?

Comment: Does setting padding-right for the close button not work? By the way, that's a nice looking tab bar.

Comment: I tried setting padding-right, but if I set a value of 10px as right padding, it reduces the size of the close button for some reason :(

Comment: What about increasing margin-right of the tab bar?

Comment: No luck with that too, since close-button is not a sub control of the tab itself, rather a subcontrol of the tab-bar, is it possible to move the position of close-button at all, I tried a lot of things, with regards to padding,margin, border setting, still I can't see it even moving

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT :** I know this post is old, but I hope it could help someone else.

After a couple of tests, I think there is one way to do this, but it does not use `Qt style sheets` :

1. Subclass your `QTabWidget` to have complete access to the protected features
2. Create your own `QWidget` or `QPushButton` as your close button
3. Manage the position of your button with the stylesheet property (`margin-right` for example)
4. Add your button to the tab `tabBar()->setTabButton(index, QTabBar::RightSide, closeButton);`

The code I used for the test :

```
MyTab::MyTab(QWidget *parent) : QTabWidget(parent)
{
/// Create your button
QPushButton *close = new QPushButton(this);

// Add a tab
addTab(new QWidget(), QIcon(), "Tab 1");
setStyleSheet("QTabBar::tab { width : 150px;}");

// Size and move your button
close->setStyleSheet("max-height: 14px; max-width: 15px; margin-right: 50px;");

// Add your button to the tab
tabBar()->setTabButton(0, QTabBar::RightSide, close);
}
```

Finally, in the MainWindow, I added my own TabWidget to a layout :

```
ui->layout->addWidget(new MyTab(this));
```

The result :

[image]

But now you will have to handle the close action manually by connecting the button and get the index for a `removeTab(index)` call.

Comment: You are welcome for the answer, as you saw, English is not my native language so many thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same thing as you do, here is my stylesheet:

```
QTabBar::close-button{
    image:url(:tabclose.png); 
    margin-right:4px;
}
```

Do not use "width" and "height" property, those two doesn't work here, setting a "image:url()" on sub controls implicitly sets the width and height of the sub-control (unless the image in a SVG).

Use "margin-right" property to control the distance from the right edge of the tab;

Comment: interesting, I'll try and get back

Comment: nope, it's not working, when I increase the margin further (6px) close button start shrinking instead of moving towards left from right edge of the tab

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom button is a good answer.but if you use margin to decide close-button's position,the close-button's mouse area will be abnormal,so I add a SpacerItem and button in a widget,finally add this widget to TabWidget.

```
void TabBarCloseable::tabInserted(int index)
{
    QWidget *widget = new QWidget(this);
    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    widget->setLayout(layout);

    QToolButton *closeBtn = new QToolButton(this);
    layout->addWidget(closeBtn);
    layout->insertSpacing(1, 15);
    closeBtn->setStyleSheet("max-height: 16px; max-width: 16px;");

    this->setTabButton(index, QTabBar::RightSide, widget);

    QTabBar::tabInserted(index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong padding

[image]

Top

```
QTabBar::tab {
    min-width: 25ex;
    padding: 10px 50px 10px 10px;
}
```

buttom

```
QTabBar::tab {
    min-width: 25ex;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a pure stylesheet solution, without creating the buttons manually:

```
QTabBar::close-button {
    image: url(:/tab-close.png);
    padding-left: -13px;
}
```

If you check the Qt source, the image painting code uses only the padding values, not the margin values.